# Web content display all files in document library

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I'm trying to use a Web content Display to show all the files in a particular folder of document library.

I would like to keep customize the choice of the folder.

Do you know if exist a dynamic element in template that point to a folder not to a specific field in the document library?

If is not possible someone know a different way to do that?

thanks in advance

Sabrina

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create structure that holds text field for folderId named "folderId".

Than create template

```
#set($service = $serviceLocator.findService("com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.service.DLFileEntryLocalService"))
#set($gid = $getterUtil.getLong($request.get("theme-display").get("scope-group-id")))
#set($fid = $getterUtil.getLong($folderId.getData()))

#set($files = $service.getFileEntries($gid, $fid))

#foreach($doc in $files)
    #set($uet = $httpUtil.encodeURL($htmlUtil.unescape($doc.getTitle())))
    <a href="/documents/$gid/$fid/$uet">$doc.getTitle()</a><br />
#end
```

Create article by that template/structure and enter folder id that you want to display. Add "Web content display" portlet that displays this article.

UPDATE:

For Liferay 6.1 method signature was changed and is

```
List<DLFileEntry>   getFileEntries(long groupId, long folderId, int start, int end, OrderByComparator obc)
```

So for liferay 6.1 you should change call to be at least

```
#set($files = $service.getFileEntries($gid, $fid, -1, -1, null))
```

or change for start/end/sort.

Comment: Hi @Martin,
Thank for your answer, It is exactly what I need but I still have a problem…

I enabled “serviceLocator” in portal-ext.properties:

journal.template.velocity.restricted.variables=

so I checked that the service is loaded using “$service.getBeanIdentifier()”
but the $files= $service.getFileEntries($gid, $fid)  variable is always null.

I tried to call files with the path that you suggested me 
“/documents/gid/fid/name” and they exist.

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot.
Sabrina

Comment: enter folowing in template after service call: "service = $service<br/>gid = $gid<br/>fid = $fid<br/>" without quotes.
Let me now results

Comment: service = com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.service.impl.DLFileEntryLocalServiceImpl@400ac3
gid = 19
fid = 13637

Comment: Ok, so it can only be that your folder does not exists or is in another group (group id is not 19) Can you check that that folder exists and has files. Is your folder in the same comunity. Above script assumes that it is [$request.get("theme-display").get("scope-group-id"))] if not add another field in your structure and template for groupId (gid).

Comment: I tried to open a files from browser under the same path /documents/19/13637/prova.png and I found it, but if I force to get the same files from template #set($files = $service.getFileEntries(19, 13637))  and I print files.size() it return 0. Do you have any other ideas why it has not to found it? Tnx

Comment: 0 is something :) Are you making "/documents/19/13637/prova.png" request in the same browser (as editing script) and you are logged in. Do you have errors in log file?

Comment: Hmm, i uploaded image file in document library and it doesn't get displayed. Please try to put pdf/doc/txt ... file in that folder and se whether it gets displayed. Let me now ... If you need to store images and display them use image gallery.

Comment: Hi @Martin, I used Liferay 6.1, with Document and Media Display I can view files(pdf,txt,png..) in it and check the Url in the Download link. I also created a portlet with a doView function that show me the groupid and the folderid of each files.. Do you have some particular settings in your portal-ext.properties?   still Tnx Sabrina

Comment: No, but I assumed Liferay 6. I'll try it in 6.1 and let you know.

Comment: You are awesome!! Tnx Sabrina

Answer (score -1):

You could use the Document Library Display portlet to accomplish this.